# Google Play (деактивация опубликованного приложения)

Tags: google-play

По ошибке опубликовал нерабочее приложение. Убрать из публикации Рабочей версии, так чтобы осталось только Альфа-тестирование, не получается.

Действия в `google developer console`:

*Вариант №1*

1. Переключился в Расширенный режим.
2. Напротив опубликованной версии нажимаю - Деактивировать. При этом на закладке "Рабочая версия" исчезает номер сборки. Остаются три активные кнопки Опубликовать, Отменить изменения, Переключить в простой режим.
3. При попытке нажать на "Опубликовать" выдает сообщение: Не удалось сохранить приложение из-за ошибок в форме.
4. При попытке нажать на "Переключить в простой режим" выдает сообщение: Простой режим недоступен, если имеются черновики или несколько активных APK-файлов.
5. При попытке нажать на "Отменить изменения" все возвращается назад (что вполне логично).

Кнопки *"Сохранить"* нет.

*Вариант №2*

1. Нажимаю на Удалить из Google Play. При этом удаляется доступ к арк, как для Рабочей версии, так и для Альфа тестирования.
2. При попытке опубликовать новую версию для Альфа тестирования автоматически публикуется и предыдущая Рабочая версия.

Вопросы:

1. Как сохранить проведенные изменения в Варианте №1?
2. Какой другой способ дективировать приложение?

Comment: Удалось ли вам убрать открытую публикацию сохранив альфатестирование?

Answer (score 2):

[Вот здесь пишут](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/play/-xdRSM0RjQg/UcRouzlMAAAJ), что при ошибке *"Не удалось сохранить приложение из-за ошибок в форме."* нужно заполнить форму недостающей информацией и тогда приложение удалится.

> I had the same issue... Just added the information they were
>   requesting, and after that tried to unpublish my app, and it worked...
>   dumb... So seems like you have to add the missing information even
>   when you want to unpublish your app...

Нужно заполнить форму, чтобы в настройках приложения не было никаких предупреждений с восклицательными знаками, как на рисунке ниже:

[image: Google Play Console]

Возможно также стоит обратиться в [техническую поддержку Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7100415?visit_id=1-636353018727404787-422962763&hl=en&rd=2).

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в пункт `Цены и реклама`. В нем есть `Реклама` выберите одно из значений

Comment: Как это связано с вопросом?

Comment: Видимо это связано таким образом, что для того чтобы приложение удалилось нужно полностью заполнить все формы на это приложение. Автор видимо советовал проверить форму "Цены и реклама", возможно в ней что-то не заполнено.